# Using regex with highlight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to highlight all lines in `post.comment` that start with $ using regex
`<%= highlight(post.comment, /^\$.*$/) %>`

However this returns the error `no implicit conversion of Regexp into String`

How can I format this to match every string starting with $?

```
$highlight test
test
$highlight test
```

Comment: What version of  Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me on Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.2.5, assuming that `post.comment` is a string.

As an alternative, You can also try the following using `sub`:

```
raw(post.comment.gsub(/^\$.*$/) { |item| "<mark>#{item}</mark>" })
```

Comment: Anyway I can use a div class instead of mark? Also this seems to break new lines, and wont highlight the next line that also has a $

Comment: The `/^\$.*$/` regex should handle newlines properly. And yes, you can use a div class by changing the replaced text.

Comment: $highlight test /n test /n $highlight test (/n for newline) is appearing as https://i.imgur.com/Xmacnbw.png

Comment: Can you post your code? you have a space after your second `\n` so the the `^\$` anchor in the regex isn't valid, which may be the issue.

Comment: There's no space, I just used them in the comment. the exact line I'm using is `<%= raw(post.comment.sub(/^\$.*$/) { |item| "<div class='highlight'>#{item}</div>" }) %>` although it happens with <mark> tags as well

Comment: Can you post the exact value of `post.comment`, though?

Comment: Ah, use `gsub` instead of `sub` for a global find and replace.